# Modifying PDO Insert between 2 databases

Tags: php, mysql, db2

I have a script that is very close to working but I need some help on a few factors.

First of all, If I run the script as is, then I get an error in powershell: `invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

This is because of the line `orqtyc AS QUANTITY` in my select query.

The problem is, I'm not using the QUANTITY to insert in my MySQL table, but I do need to use it for some logic.
Basically, it's fine for now, but this script will run daily and I need some logic that uses the quantity.

Basically, I need to do an insert ignore of sorts, and say: If there is already a record, or records, for the unique combo of dealer/sku_id/group_id then look at the expiration date. If still within the expiration date, update the existing records. If beyond expiration date, insert new records. The only catch is: There should only be a number of records that equals the quantity within each expiration date.

I hope that makes sense, but I can clarify if need be.

Basically, I need to know how to incorporate the quantity in the select without explicitly inserting base on it, but rather use it in some looping logic to make sure the record count equals the quantity as long as within the expiration date.

My only other issue is I need to modify my insert to insert into start_date and expire_date using SHIPDATE + 7 days and SHIPDATE + 127 days respectively.

here's the current script:

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //MySql Connection credentials
    $mysqlServer = "";
    $mysqlUser = "";
    $mysqlPass = "*";

    //Establilsh MySql Connection
    $mysqlConn = new mysqli($mysqlServer, $mysqlUser, $mysqlPass);

    //establish PDO connection
    $PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=***;dbname=***', $mysqlUser, $mysqlPass);

    $PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //Check MySQL connection
    if($mysqlConn->connect_error){
      die("Connection Failed: " .$mysqlConn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected Succssfully to Mysql";

    //Establish DB2 Connection  
    $DB2Conn = odbc_connect("","", "");

    //Check DB2 Connection
    if(!$DB2Conn){
      die("Could not connect");
    }else{
        echo"Connected to DB2";
    }

    //DB2 Select query
    $plcQueryDB2 = " 

            select  
                    cstnoc AS DEALER,
                    orqtyc AS QUANTITY, --If I remove this line, it inserts perfectly
                    framec AS FRAME,
                    covr1c AS COVER,
                    colr1c AS COLOR ,
                    extd1d AS SHIPDATE
              FROM GPORPCFL
              group by invnoc,cstnoc, slsnoc, orqtyc, framec, covr1c,colr1c, extd1d
              limit 200
    ";

    var_dump ($plcQueryDB2);

    //prepare and execute on db2
    $prep = odbc_prepare($DB2Conn, $plcQueryDB2);
    $exec = odbc_execute($prep);
    $result = odbc_exec($DB2Conn, $plcQueryDB2);


    try{

        while($arr = odbc_fetch_array($result)) 
        {

            $stmt = $PDO->prepare("
                INSERT INTO placements (sku_id, group_id, dealer_id, start_date, expire_date)
                SELECT id, sku_group_id, :DEALER, :SHIPDATE + 7 day interval, :SHIPDATE + 127 day interval
                FROM skus s
                WHERE  s.frame=:FRAME AND s.cover1=:COVER AND s.color1=:COLOR
            ");

            $PDO->beginTransaction();
            $i = 0;
            while($db2row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {

                if(++$i % 1000 == 0) {
                    $PDO->commit();
                    $PDO->beginTransaction();
                }

                $stmt->execute($db2row);

            }
            $PDO->commit();
        }
    }catch (PDOException $e){
        print "ERROR!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }

    $PDO = null;
    $stmt = null;

    if (mysqli_close($mysqlConn)){
        echo "MySQL Closed";
    }



    ?>
```

Comment: Your select is separate from your insert, so that makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Which part are you referring to that makes no sense whatsoever, I can try to clarify

Comment: Copy `$db2row` into a new variable, remove the index you don't want, and then pass the new variable into `execute()` instead.  Pretty trivial.  I'm curious as to why you're doing nested fetches on the same resultset though.

Comment: @PatrickQ I had a lot more to this previously and I whittled it down, I guess that's an oversight on my part. I should remove the first fetch, thank you!